# VB.Net Play Mp3 song through microphone

Tags: vb.net, output, mp3

Alright, so I want to play music through out the microphone, it's for a game that I want to create the app for.

I've found out that there is a tool that does this already https://github.com/SilentSys/SLAM
But I'd love to get a smaller and easier snippet which I can learn from. I just want to play a simpe mp3 sound through a list of output recording devices or the active output device.

Answer (score -1):

Does it have to be mp3?

If not, you can play .wav using

```
My.Computer.Audio.Play(ExampleSong.wav, AudioPlayMode.Background)
```

Comment: I want to play sound through the microphone. Through a recoding device on my computer.